# What to write following “before”

Tags: grammar

I have two question first I’d like to know whether the sentence: “Don’t get on the care before I **came** back” is correct or not. Second question, is if the sentence above happens to be correct would the sentence: “ I’d better put in the work before my mother arrived” correct?
Thanks

Comment: On this site, we don't do proofreading. If you have a question about a specific aspect of English you're unsure about, please use the "Edit" button to make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your tense is incorrect. You can't use the past tense because "it" hasn't happened yet (I have not come back and your mother has not arrived). Also, the word "care" doesn't make sense so I substituted "bus".

> Don't get on the *bus* before I **come** back.

> I'd better put in the work before my mother **arrives**.